# Grouping rows based on a date field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table **exams.sql** with exam scores in SQL Server. It saves the student's ID, their score, and the test date.

```
CREATE TABLE exams (
  student_id INTEGER,
  score INTEGER,
  date DATE
);

INSERT INTO exams VALUES (1, 2, '2021-01-06');
INSERT INTO exams VALUES (1, 8, '2021-01-09');
INSERT INTO exams VALUES (2, 10, '2021-02-14');
INSERT INTO exams VALUES (3, 9, '2021-02-26');
INSERT INTO exams VALUES (3, 7, '2021-03-30');
```

The problem begins when a student takes the exam two (or more) times. I need the complete list of students with their actual qualification: in case they have been evaluated more than once, **take the last date**.

| student_id | score | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-01-06 |
| 1 | 8 | 2021-01-09 |
| 2 | 10 | 2021-02-14 |
| 3 | 9 | 2021-02-26 |
| 3 | 7 | 2021-03-30 |

The result of the query should be:

| student_id | score | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 2021-01-09 |
| 2 | 10 | 2021-02-14 |
| 3 | 7 | 2021-03-30 |

This was my attempt:

```
Select student_id, score, max(date) from exams
Group by student_id
```

And I get the following error message.

```
Column 'score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

But I can't add 'score' to 'group by' since being different scores, I would have several rows per student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from exams e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `WITH TIES`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  exams
 Order By row_number() over (partition by student_id order by date desc)
```

**Full Disclosure:**  Gordons approach is a nudge more performant